# Error on run build app: is not allowed to show TctSplashScreen

Tags: android-studio

i m getting a crash on build SUCCESSFUL in 6s

Errors:

```
com...ple.thunderbolt_108.serverapp  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp, PID: 22010
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp/com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3814)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3980)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:115)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2355)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:217)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:309)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8199)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1009)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.ReflectionUtils.getValue(ReflectionUtils.java:29)
                                                                                                        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:203)
                                                                                                        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
                                                                                                        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:245)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1133)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1025)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:723)
                                                                                                        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1003)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:772)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
                                                                                                        at com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8104)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8084)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1339)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3787)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3980)
2023-06-20 19:04:45.106 22010-22010 AndroidRuntime          com...ple.thunderbolt_108.serverapp  E      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:115)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2355)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:217)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:309)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8199)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1009)
2023-06-20 19:04:45.112 22010-22100 FA                      com...ple.thunderbolt_108.serverapp  V  App measurement setting deferred collection: false
2023-06-20 19:04:45.129 22010-22100 FA                      com...ple.thunderbolt_108.serverapp  D  Resetting session stitching token to not null
2023-06-20 19:04:45.142 22010-22039 DxoMonitorNotifier      com...ple.thunderbolt_108.serverapp  V  service==null
2023-06-20 19:04:45.153 22010-22010 Process                 com...ple.thunderbolt_108.serverapp  I  Sending signal. PID: 22010 SIG: 9
2023-06-20 19:04:45.255  1821-3336  TctSplashS...Controller system_server                        E  com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp is not allowed to show TctSplashScreen!
```

I was asked to update imports and dependencies for androidx, eliminate duplicate libraries and now the app starts but stops before opening.

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp.Common.Common;
import com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp.Model.User;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;
import info.hoang8f.widget.FButton;
import io.paperdb.Paper;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FButton btnsignin;
    TextView txtslogan;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Vahika.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnsignin=(FButton) findViewById(R.id.signin);

        txtslogan=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSlogan);
        Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Vahika.ttf");
        txtslogan.setTypeface(typeface);

        Paper.init(this);

        btnsignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent SignIn=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignInAct.class);
                startActivity(SignIn);
            }
        });

        //Check Remember
        String user=Paper.book().read(Common.USER_KEY);
        String pwd=Paper.book().read(Common.PWD_KEY);
        if (user!=null && pwd!=null)
        {
            if (!user.isEmpty() && !pwd.isEmpty())
                login(user,pwd);
        }
    }

    private void login(String phone, String pwd) {
        //Save user & Password
        //Init firebase
        FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference users =database.getReference("User");
        final AlertDialog dialog=new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(MainActivity.this).build();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setMessage("Verificar Wifi . . . 2 seg. . .");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        final String localPhone=phone;
        final String localPassword=pwd;
        users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(localPhone).exists()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    //Get user info
                    User user = dataSnapshot.child(localPhone).getValue(User.class);
                    user.setPhone(localPhone); //set phone
                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(user.getIsStaff()))
                    {
                        if (user.getPassword().equals(localPassword)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign In Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent login=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class);
                            startActivity(login);
                            Common.currentUser=user;
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Erraste, cuidado com Brute force! Vai tentando..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contacta o programador, estás a entrar com conta indevida.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Utilizador não exite em base de dados!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML activity_main.cxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/slogan"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/signin"
            android:text="Entrar no Server"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:fButtonColor="@color/fbutton_color_transparent"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I corrected the macros that in turn would have given an error because of the duplicated libraries, and revised the library:
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' which doesn't support more than 1.6.1 because it gives macros error, I put android:exported="true" where there are the intent filters in manifest, in grandle properties I put: android .useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true, in the defaultConfig I put multiDexEnabled true in grandle app and in relation to the library in the implementation dependencies 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'.

Any help can be useful, as I have already updated the IDE; caches, reset the phone, upgrade dependencies, even duplicate ones.
Thanks